# Is it possible to modify a push notification after it has been received?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

For example, if I receive an @mention on a twitter app, I might get a notification like:

```
    "You have 1 new mention"
```

If I receive another @mention before I opened the previous push notification, I'd like it to update to:

```
    "You have 2 new mentions"
```

rather than send another notification like the first and end up with:

```
    "You have 1 new mention"
    "You have 1 new mention"
```

on the lock screen.

Comment: Did you find the solution for your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am probably saying the obvious but just to make things clear.

**Notification has been sent** and **Notification has been received** are two different states (Ambiguity in your question)

A *sent* notification hasn't been necessarily delivered to the user. If new notification arrives on the APN server before the previous has been delivered, it will be discarded and only the newer one will be sent to the user.

For situation like this, when new notification arrives on the APN server before the previous has been delivered you would need a mechanism of knowing the number of "unread" messages/mentions.

A *received* notification is one that has been delivered to the device and depending on the state of the application (terminated/active/in background) you can react to it.

There is no way of modifying once sent (and received) notification but you can obviously update the badge number for the application to show to the user the number of "unread" notifications.

Therefore I would suggest perhaps a better usability of the notification message.

- Notification from whom
- The actual mention message
- etc.

as the badge number is better used for the amount of new notifications.